# Restoring OEM windows macrium image to a new different make PC with retail Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, system-restore, oem, macrium

I have a Dell 8700 PC that ran Windows 10 home 64 bit.  The motherboard spontaneously let the smoke out of one of the chips and the PC is now unserviceable.  A recent image was made of the Windows installation with Macrium Reflect Free.  I can get an ex-lease Acer small form factor desktop with similar specs for less than the cost of a new motherboard, so the plan is to get one of those and restore the Macrium image.

I gather that OEM installations of Windows can't be restored onto different hardware however, so I'm looking to buy a Windows 10 Pro 64-bit license for the replacement machine.

My questions:
I'm unsure as to the procedure, or whether this will fly.  I'm assuming I install the new Win10 pro on the new machine first, them boot from the rescue image and restore.  I've read that Windows will silently reactivate itself if it finds the same flavour (home or pro) on the new machine, but what will happen if it finds a higher-spec'ed flavour (pro) when it goes to restore?

Comment: The best way to install a Retail install of Windows 10 is to modify your ISO so it will install any image by modifying a text file.  ". I've read that Windows will silently reactivate itself if it finds the same flavour (home or pro) on the new machine, but what will happen if it finds a higher-spec'ed flavor (pro) when it goes to restore?" - This i solved by simply install that edition you want.

Comment: Not sure I understand - can you point me at a resource?

Comment: `ei.cfg` contained within sources.  If you make the ISO a Retail ISO then it won't activate with an OEM license.  This is how you install Windows 10 Professional on a device that came with Windows 10 Home directly.

Answer (score 0):

When there's a difference in components between the original mobo and the replacement, Windows either may not boot, or may only boot into Safe mode.  However, it should work well enough for you to extract your data onto another drive.

If it does not object, or only shows you the 'Not Activated' bug-on-the-windshield overlay, then carry on, and activate using your retail license key.  If it objects, then you will need to perform a complete reinstall after you've recovered data.

Comment: My reading of the macrium docs is that it's pretty clever when it comes to dealing with hardware differences - it gives you am opportunity to point at a drivers image when it detects a conflict.  I would be happy to work from a clean install, were it not for the masses of installed software I would rather not have to reinstall