# Transferring an existing Windows disk from a dead PC to another one and avoiding reinstall of applications

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, clone, system-restore, macrium

(this question is really a follow-on from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1529789/restoring-oem-windows-macrium-image-to-a-new-different-make-pc-with-retail-windo))

I have a dead Dell computer where the cause of death did not involve or damage the hard drive.

If I had identical replacement hardware, I could just physically transfer the existing disk and all would be well.  I don't however, and I'm faced with building the new machine (non-Dell) from scratch and installing a ton of applications again.  I have a license for Win10 Pro retail for the new machine (the dead machine was Win10 Home OEM).

I'm very keen to avoid reinstallation of my applications.  Would this work (and is this the right order to do things)?

1. use Macrium Reflect to clone the old disk onto another new one of the same or greater size.
2. boot the new machine in safe mode, and use Device Manager to remove all the hardware devices that aren't present in the new machine.
3. reboot and let plug-and-pray get the appropriate drivers for the new hardware.
4. upgrade the Win10 installation to Win10 Pro retail.

**UPDATE**

Here's what happened:

- old machine was Dell 8700 running Win10 Home, 2TB drive, 16G RAM. Nvidia GTX745 video card.
- new machine was ex-lease Acer I7 with SSD only, 16G RAM, GT730 video card
- bought a new 2TB drive.
- plugged the old 2TB drive into the Acer.
- removed the SSD from the Acer (the motherboard only had 2 power connectors).
- plugged the new 2TB drive into the Acer.
- booted the Acer from the 8700's Macrium Reflect rescue media.
- used Reflect to clone the old 2TB drive to the new one.
- powered down the Acer, removed the old 2TB drive and rebooted.  Windows started and worked fine but with a default Microsoft video driver.
- enabled the device manager option that allows you to view "hidden" devices, found the GTX745, removed it and rebooted.  Plug and Pray installed the GT730 video drivers.
- everything seems to be intact and works as it should.

Upgrading the Windows installation from Home to Pro was (apparently) just a matter of accessing Settings/Security/Activation and pasting in the key. 
 I did this, and Windows now announces as an activated Pro version installation, but it thinks that it is activated through a digital license rather than a product key.  This may be because the old license was an OEM one.

Comment: Your first step is admirable. Backing up your original and performing your "risky" process gives you a nice safe fail mode. I've done as you describe, without the clone portion, with limited success, but that was pre-Win-10, hence my comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  So my understanding is that you tried 2,3,4 (I've edited the questions and numbered them) and had some success? - I'm encouraged.!

Comment: This question has been asked countless times, but I am too lazy to look for a duplicate.  Its possible just to put the drive in the new computer and it will work fine.  There is no harm in trying.

Comment: question updated with results.

Answer (score 1):

As per knowledge experience and viewpoint yes its possibility to clone and migrate the OS and I have done many time but with windows 98 XP and 7 8 but not with windows 10

But main  basic necessity is that  the motherboard its chipset north bridge south bridge chips processor should be SIMILAR exactly same models in new PC as of dead PC as windows 7 8 10 installs drivers of board and chipset automatically while installing windows and it also write configuration settings in many config and system files which is hard to find and remove and these drivers and configurations crashes when windows installs in other motherboard configuration changes

You can give a try for windows 10 but the motherboard chipset and processor should be same if not same and its ur luck an give a try that you can use many software of disk cloning

1. use Macrium Reflect or acronis disk director and many to clone the old disk onto another new one of the same or greater size.
2. boot the new machine in SAFE MODE and use Device Manager to remove all the hardware  ALL CHIPSET SYSTEM DRIVERS devices that ARE SAME OR aren't present in the neweat ( remove all)
3. reboot and let plug-and-play get the appropriate drivers for the new hardware upgrade the Win10 installation to Win10 Pro retail.

In my case in my computer lab I have 20 PC with same motherboard HDD ram and same cabinets even and I install one PC clone or backup image  it and install it other 20 PC regularly and I have kept that image file for recovery every time i get problem I restore the image

At time of windows 98  we used to copy the disk files without cloning to any different PC  motherboard processor chipset and remove hardware from device manger and it works fine and also in windows xp sp1  but windows  7 8 10 crashes

For copying migrating  installed software's installations there many tools softwares ( zinstalls, laplink,  EaseUS Todo PCTrans ) are available which can copy and migrate installed software's or you can use portable softwares but windows ( AOMEI Backupper Professional Edition,  MiniTool ShadowMaker ) its you have to try programs I have not used or tried them only searches for you or find some more tools to migrate it into different hardware which one can work

[How to Transfer Operating System from One Computer to Another - MiniTool](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.minitool.com/amp/backup-tips/transfer-os-from-one-computer-to-another.html&ved=2ahUKEwiP-YP7vIHoAhWBzzgGHc5-BO8QFjASegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw0Cu6P9eqEd2S285TO7YSWB&ampcf=1)

[Simple Way to Move a Windows 10 Hard Drive to a New Computer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/move-hard-drive-to-new-computer-windows-10.amp.html&ved=2ahUKEwioh8XMvYHoAhUu63MBHaD8DoE4ChAWMAN6BAgIEAE&usg=AOvVaw2VdviO2JmLBUaiCHHnCHd4)

http://www.zinstall.com/how-to/how-to-transfer-programs-and-files-to-windows-10

If you have license number then unregister and then reregistration license key of windows 10

Press Windows key + X then click Command Prompt (Admin). At the command prompt, enter the following command: slmgr.vbs /upk. This command uninstalls the product key, which frees the license for use elsewhere. You are now free to transfer your license to another computer

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/transfer-windows-10-license-new-pc/amp/

If you don't have license key then see following links

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/transfer-windows-10-home-oem-license-to-a-new-pc/3a1a105d-087d-474a-aa94-2bbcce307d71

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-transfer-windows-10-license-new-computer-or-hard-drive

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=woZ68FmSnq4

Comment: What about the license, it wont activate on a different motherboard.

Comment: @Moab license details added

Answer (score 1):

1. use Macrium Reflect to clone the old disk onto another new one of
   the same or greater size.
2. boot the new machine from a windows 10 dvd/usb

   - SHIFT F10 to get command prompt
   - use **dir** to identify what the drive letter is for the windows partition
   - dism /image:d:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:e:\Drivers /recurse

   where d: is the windows install and e: is a source of drivers

   - DISM.exe /Image:C:\test\offline /Get-Drivers
   - DISM.exe /Image:C:\test\offline /Remove-Driver /Driver:oem1.inf
3. reboot and let plug-and-pray get the appropriate drivers for the new hardware.
4. upgrade the Win10 installation to Win10 Pro retail